# mysql select row number query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with this query im trying to select the row number based on (upvotes - downvotes) in a certain subset of a table , but i need to also reset the @rownum within the same query:

This query works but I need to run two of them. Anyway to combine the set @rownum into one query my attempts have been in vain.

```
SET @rownum = 0;
SELECT rank  
FROM (SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS 
rank FROM Cars where Auto_SET = 'BMW'
order by (upvotes-downvotes) DESC) d
WHERE ID = 391802
```

This one throws an error:

```
SELECT rank 
FROM (SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS 
rank FROM Cars  where Auto_SET = 'BMW' , 
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by 
(upvotes-downvotes) DESC) d
WHERE ID = 391913
```

Comment: Throws an error. What error and where?

Answer (score 1):

The `cross-join` should be along with the `select from table_name` something like

```
SELECT rank 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
  @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank 
  FROM Cars ,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
  where Auto_SET = 'BMW' 
  order by 
 (upvotes-downvotes) DESC
) d
WHERE ID = 391913
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should also work:

```
SELECT @rn := @rn+1 AS RANK,t1.* FROM (

 # Your query here.
 SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Auto_SET = 'BMW' 
 WHERE ID = 391913 ORDER BY (upvotes-downvotes) DESC

) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

Good luck!!